# Failed openWeatherMap API call

Tags: reactjs, api, github, heroku, openweathermap

Been working on a small react app that uses the openWeatherMap API to retrieve the current weather conditions for a given location.

The app works flawlessly when tested locally on my system. However, it is failing to return results when deployed to both Github and Heroku.

I've tried practically everything but no way. I even hard-coded the API call to the address bar of my browser and results were returned but when the same search string was hard-coded into the app, the call failed!

Anyone with an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's is the code block (with hard-coded parameters) where the API call is being made:

```
fetch(
     "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=durban&appid=d6e0e85a41968aaf6240b5ed27522ebd"
   )
```

Thank you in advance.

N.B: The error being returned is: Failed to fetch

Here is the full fetch function:

```
  function getForecast(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Next, make the call to the openweathermap API, with the parameters for the specified city
    // fetch(
    //   `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=${unit}&q=${city}&appid=${keys.openweathermap_API_KEY}`
    // )
   
fetch(
     "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=durban&appid=d6e0e85a41968aaf6240b5ed27522ebd"
   )

      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(
        (response) => {
          setResponseObj(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          alert("Error in fetching weather data : " + error.message);
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: can you show the full fetch function?

Comment: Edited to include the full fetch function

Comment: This code seems to work for me as well. I think you need to use https for the URL since the browser would reject http requests on a website which has https enabled

Comment: As it turned out - Kenny John Jacob was somehow right! (in a sense). The problem was the use of the secured http protocol in the app url (as generated by the Heroku deployment module). If the app is accessed with only http, the api call works like charm. I couldn't have guessed this in a million years. Thanks all the same Jacob

Comment: From your comment, what I understand is that you have disabled https for your website, is it? In the future if you are making any apps with sensitive data involved, you should stick to fully using https :)

Comment: Of course. But in this particular instance, there is nothing sensitive about the weather conditions for a location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work for me as well. You may need to use https for the URL since the browser would reject http requests on a website which has https enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out - Kenny John Jacob was somehow right! (in a sense). The problem was the use of the secured http protocol in the app url (as generated by the Heroku deployment module). If the app is accessed with only http, the api call works like charm. I couldn't have guessed this in a million years. Thanks all the same Jacob

Comment: I can rewrite my comment as an answer and you can mark that as the correct answer so that others can easily identify.